# Android Application Installed but won't open on device

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt, nfc

I created an application on Android. I am developing it on eclipse with ADT.

It is about nfc. For the moment it only reads and writes tag.

I run my application on my mobile device for testing and it works well.

So it compiles well and runs well on my Xperia Z1 Sony, however when i unplug my phone and install the apk on it i have a problem :

The install runs well but then i have two choices "Terminated" or "Open".
The open is not clickable... I go to settings->Application->installed and i see my app that is install. I can force stop clear cache but not open it... I can't understand why.

It runs well on my phone when i launch it from eclipse but when i want to run it on my phone unplugged from my computer it doesn't want to be open. No error message during installation...

I activate dev mode and allow installation from unknown sources ect...

Do someone have a clue ??

Here is my manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mynfc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mynfc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
<activity android:name=".WriteATagActivity"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate the intent filters into the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For an intent filter to match, action, category and data should be correct. When you open the app via the icon, it will send a intent with MAIN action, and category LAUNCHER. Because it does not contain a data type, and because the category does not match DEFAULT and action does not match NDEF_DISCOVERED, Android thinks your intent filter can not handle it.

Comment: Thanks man, you save me !! I understand what was the problem thanks to you :)!